# Como fazer instalar SVN no Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn

Quero instalar o repositório do SVN no Eclipse. Como proceder?

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic quarto item da lista da pergunta. Totalmente no escopo. E tem este também http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1820/queremos-perguntas-que-tratem-de-dificuldades-na-instala%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ou-uso-de-ferrament

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No menu vá em Help > Install new software. Em Work with selecione --All Availables Sites-- . Irá aparecer uma lista de
opções, clique na seta da opção General Purpose Tools e selecione o Marketplace Client e depois clique em Next. O Marketplace
será instalado e o eclipse reiniciado. Vá em Help > Eclipse Marketplace... e pesquise por SVN. Escolha um svn e clique em Install.
Eu recomendo o Subvirse - SVN Team Provider é o que eu uso no trabalho.

Answer (score 0):

Vá no menu `Help > Eclipse Market Place`.
Pesquise por um plugin chamado Subclipse. Instale ele. Ai é só utilizar.